# How do I find out the process id of the backgrounded process?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, daemon, nohup

I've got a command (program) that I'd like to run with nohup and background it. Like

```
nohup command > logfile.txt &
```

How do I find out the process ID? I would like to be able to write the process id in a file, read it later and kill the process programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your script:

```
nohup command > logfile.txt &
echo $! > /var/run/command.pid
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$!`.  Referenced in the [bash documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ps` and `grep` to find the process in the process list and then `awk` to parse the output and find the actual PID:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep YOUR_PROCESS_NAME | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

ps aux | grep -v grep | grep *program name*

That'll check the running processes, grep for the program name, but exclude the grep itself.

Comment: This solution would not work because I run multiple instances of the same program (2 to be exact), and I need to differentiate between them. EDIT: I _think_ it wouldn't work... would it? :)